# Find Network Request on Site Given Known Text

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

So, I have a website I'm interested in writing an API for. I go to the Network tab under dev-tools to find the API call, but am not finding it given that there's just a lot.

Is there a way to find a network request given that I know say a string that will be in the response?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, you know the string that will be in the response. So you can do the following in your browser.

Enter developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd>)

Go under the network tab

Refresh your browser

Click on any URL  [Image reference here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGEbj.png)

On your keyboard hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>. You will see a search function provided.

Search the string that you are looking for. [Image reference here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCkVR.png)

And done! You can get your API call that you are looking for.